# href # is not appending to end of URL

Tags: javascript, html

href # is not appending to end of URL

I have written the html page on which one of the anchor tag has href "#". Whenever I am clicking on it, # is not appending at the end of URL path in browser. Same functionality is working in different websites. Please suggest..

```
<li class="nav-item d-md-down-none">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <i class="icon-location-pin"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
```

My current url is `"http://localhost:8080/add/AddDocument.html"`

After clicking on the link i should get `"http://localhost:8080/add/AddDocument.html#"`

But i am getting this `"http://localhost:8080/add/#"`

Comment: All else being equal, you will not get that behaviour.

Comment: How are you appending your `href` ? Where is your javascript code ?

Comment: Without asking why you want that behaviour, href="#" actually makes what you want. You have probably a routing problem.

Comment: the code you have posted is working fine on my browser. please post the code where you are appending href="#". and which browser you are using ?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem. Something is causing the change in URL. Maybe JavaScript. Maybe something else. The advice behind that link will have you narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved.

There is `<base href=”/”>` tag present in my html which was loading alternative html link while clicking on `href="#"`.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, it is to link to part of a page `('#about')`. If it is just there instead of being `empty('#' vs. '')`, it prevents the page from being reloaded on click.

Normally, you define it like this:

```
<a href="#about"></a>
<div id="about"></a>
```

In order for your `href` to have a clickable link ie a web address, by placing the hashtag symbol, you refer the element (image,text, video etc) as a `href` if the website link is either not yet available or if it’s in the same page you can use the hashtag followed by the id name.

Also please check your routing.

Comment: The question is asking about a specific problem. You don't appear to have addressed that **at all** and are just spouting some random facts about the use of `#` symbols in URLs.

Comment: A hashtag is a means of indicating that a term, in plain text, should be hyperlinked as a search term (on social media networks). It gets the name because it it uses a hash character to prefix it. Most things (including what is being asked about here) that use a hash symbol are not hashtags.